# How to write multiple lists into a dataframe using loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have several lists that are generated from a `get_topic()` function. That is,

```
list1 = get_topic(1)
list2 = get_topic(2)
and another dozens of lists.

# The list contains something like

[('A', 0.1),('B', 0.2),('C',0.3)]
```

I am trying to write a loop so that all different lists can be saved to different columns in a dataframe. The code I tried was:

```
for i in range(1,number) # number is the total number of lists + 1
    df_02 = pd.DataFrame(get_topic(i)
```

This only returns with list1, but no other lists. The result that I would like to get is something like:

| List 1 | Number 1 | List 2 | Number 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.1 | D | 0.03 |
| B | 0.2 | E | 0.04 |
| C | 0.3 | F | 0.05 |

Could anyone help me to correct the loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new DataFrame at every iteration.

This will create a structure similar to what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([get_topic(i) for i in range(1, number)])
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.transpose()
```

Result:

```
   0    1  2    3  4    5
0  A  0.1  D  0.1  G  0.1
1  B  0.2  E  0.2  H  0.2
2  C  0.3  F  0.3  I  0.3
```

One-liner version:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([get_topic(i) for i in range(1, number)]).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True).transpose()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second line transferred all the lists into one single list and didn't quite work out. However, after deleting it, I have been able to get a similar format as what I want. Thank you again for the ideas!

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, number):
    df[f'List {i}'], df[f'Number {i}'] = zip(*get_topic(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I reconstruct a hypothetical get_topic() function that simply fetches a list from a list of lists.

The idea is to use [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in order to concatenate dataframes at each iteration.

```py
import pandas as pd

topics = [
    [('A', 0.1), ('B', 0.2), ('C', 0.3)],
    [('D', 0.3), ('E', 0.4), ('F', 0.5)]
]
number = len(topics)


def get_topic(index) -> []:
    return topics[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(0, number):  # number is the total number of lists
        curr_topic = get_topic(i)
        curr_columns = ['List ' + str(i+1), 'Number ' + str(i+1)]
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data=curr_topic, columns=curr_columns)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output will be:

```
  List 1  Number 1 List 2  Number 2
0      A       0.1      D       0.3
1      B       0.2      E       0.4
2      C       0.3      F       0.5
```